# Add custom customer attributes in Magento 1.4.2

Tags: magento, attributes, custom-fields

how can I add custom fields to customer attributes in backend with the Magento version 1.4.2

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can install Pol Attribute Manager: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/mathphp/extension/898/attributes-manager/reviews

Comment: it's not compatible with Magento 1.4.2 !

Comment: Maybe you need to do some workarounds to get working, but works. I'm using both 1.4.2 and 1.5.

Comment: If you can, just you can analyse the eav_attribute table and insert rows, but is a bit complicated if you don't know magento's database structure. Maybe this link can help you too: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/customers_and_accounts/registration_fields

Comment: I don't have on hands, but you can try and tell me what errors happens.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a new attribute for customer entity using installer. You can find examples in the following files (search by `addAttribute`)

`app/code/core/Mage/Customer/sql/customer_setup/mysql4-upgrade-1.4.0.0.0-1.4.0.0.1.php`

`mage14/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/sql/customer_setup/mysql4-upgrade-1.4.0.0.2-1.4.0.0.3.php`

Comment: Thanks vsushkov, can you provide more details, if you have already done a thing like it... ?